# Continuity of an $\mathbb {R}^2$ function

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity

Let $f$ be an $\mathbb{R}^2$ endomorphism and $N:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^+$ 
defined by $$\forall u \in \mathbb {R }^2, N(u) = ||f(u)|| $$

I need to show $N$ is continuous.

The problem is that $N$ is only a seminorm, otherwise it would have verified Lipschitz criterion and I'd be done.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the big deal? $f$ is an endomorphism, which means it's continuous, and $||\cdot||:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ is a continuous function, and composition of continuous functions is continuous. Done!

Comment: "f is an endomorphism, which means it's continuous" I didn't know about that...

Comment: Well, let's start there. What is the definition of "endomorphism" from your book?

Comment: it's a linear function defined from $\mathbb{R}^2$ with values in $\mathbb{R}^2$ . Nothing in particular is about continuity in this definition though

Comment: I see a [linear-algebra] tag, so I assume you mean this in the sense of a vector space, i.e. $f(x)=(ax_1+bx_2,cx_1+dx_2)$. Written this way, it's clearly continuous, because linear functions are continuous (this may need a proof, depending on how obvious this is to you).

Comment: No it can't be such a simple function, it just has to be linear

Comment: I've addressed your concerns in an answer. (You may not have been notified.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's prove that a linear function is continuous. Recalling the definition:

> A function $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^k$ is **continuous** iff for each $x\in\Bbb{R}^n$ and for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $y\in\Bbb{R}^n$ with $||y-x||<\delta$ we have $||f(y)-f(x)||<\epsilon$.

Now if $f$ is linear, then it takes the form $f(x)=Ax$ for some $k\times n$ matrix $A$. Then

$$||f(y)-f(x)||=||Ay-Ax||=||A(y-x)||,$$

and we want to show that this is less than $C||y-x||$ for some constant $C$ dependent on $A$ only. This would finish the proof, because for any $\epsilon$, if we let $\delta=\epsilon/C$ we have that

$$||f(y)-f(x)||=||A(y-x)||\le C||y-x||<C\delta=\epsilon,$$

and so $f$ is continuous.

But let's back up the claim that for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$, $||Ax||\le C||x||$ for some $C$. (The smallest upper bound for $C$ here is conventionally called the induced [matrix norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm) $||A||$.) An easy-to-prove upper bound here is the Frobenius norm, defined by $||A||_F^2=\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}^2$.

Writing out all these norms as sums (and squaring both sides for convenience):
$$||Ax||^2=\sum_{i=1}^k\left(\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}x_j\right)^2$$
$$||A||_F^2||x||^2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}^2\right)\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2=\sum_{i=1}^k\left(\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}^2\cdot\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2\right)$$

We wish to prove that $||Ax||^2\le ||A||_F^2||x||^2$, but given the above expressions, this reduces to

$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}x_j\right)^2\le\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}^2\cdot\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2,$$

which is exactly the famous [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality). This completes the proof.

---

Now that we know that linear functions are continuous, let's return to the problem. We want to know that an endomorphism of $\Bbb{R}^2$, i.e. a linear function $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$, composed with the norm operation $||\cdot||:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$, is continuous. If it is accepted that the norm operation is continuous and the composition of continuous functions is continuous, then the above proof is sufficient to prove that $N(x)=||f(x)||$ is continuous.

Although the above was proven in full generality of $\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^k$, for application to the problem we need only $\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$, and the only linear functions $\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$ are functions of the form $f(x)=Ax$ for $A$ a $2\times2$ matrix; this yields the representation $f(x)=(ax_1+bx_2,cx_1+dx_2)$. Note that these functions (choosing arbitrary constant $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb{R}$) are the *only* endomorphisms of $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Very nice and clear proof. I'll be thinking more of morphisms in terms of matrix in the future. Thans for your help !